# C++ SHA-256 Basic Implementation doesn't match proper SHA-256

Tags: c++, sha256

I'm trying to implement Wikipedia page pseudo-code of SHA-256 on [SHA-2 page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

My data input has byte granularity, I put everything on stack (efficiency is not the focus at this point). I create separate array, where I keep padding end of the last 512-bit chunk. I followed every letter, but evidently something is wrong, and my result doesn't match the SHA-256. I looked at other implementations, but didn't find any discrepancies (although some of them are a mess to read). I've been trying to make this work for many hours, but it still doesn't match, while every individual part of the code seems to work correctly (which must be wrong). I would really appreciate some help.

Implementation for little-endian device.

Test string: "G" of length 1 byte (0x47).

```
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t LeftRotate(uint32_t data, uint32_t rotation) {
    return (data << rotation) | (data >> (32 - rotation));
}

uint32_t RightRotate(uint32_t data, uint32_t rotation) {
    return (data >> rotation) | (data << (32 - rotation));
}

uint32_t ReverseBytes(uint32_t Input) {
    return ((Input & 0x000000FF) << 24) | ((Input & 0x0000FF00) << 8)
            | ((Input & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((Input & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

int main() {
    uint8_t Data[64] alignas(8) = {0};
            Data[0] = 'G';
            uint32_t InputByteLength = 1; //Not using all array, to test it easily with online calculators

            uint32_t Hash[8] = {0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A,
                0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19};

            uint32_t RoundConstants[64] = {0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF,
                0xE9B5DBA5, 0x3956C25B, 0x59F111F1, 0x923F82A4, 0xAB1C5ED5,
                0xD807AA98, 0x12835B01, 0x243185BE, 0x550C7DC3, 0x72BE5D74,
                0x80DEB1FE, 0x9BDC06A7, 0xC19BF174, 0xE49B69C1, 0xEFBE4786,
                0x0FC19DC6, 0x240CA1CC, 0x2DE92C6F, 0x4A7484AA, 0x5CB0A9DC,
                0x76F988DA, 0x983E5152, 0xA831C66D, 0xB00327C8, 0xBF597FC7,
                0xC6E00BF3, 0xD5A79147, 0x06CA6351, 0x14292967, 0x27B70A85,
                0x2E1B2138, 0x4D2C6DFC, 0x53380D13, 0x650A7354, 0x766A0ABB,
                0x81C2C92E, 0x92722C85, 0xA2BFE8A1, 0xA81A664B, 0xC24B8B70,
                0xC76C51A3, 0xD192E819, 0xD6990624, 0xF40E3585, 0x106AA070,
                0x19A4C116, 0x1E376C08, 0x2748774C, 0x34B0BCB5, 0x391C0CB3,
                0x4ED8AA4A, 0x5B9CCA4F, 0x682E6FF3, 0x748F82EE, 0x78A5636F,
                0x84C87814, 0x8CC70208, 0x90BEFFFA, 0xA4506CEB, 0xBEF9A3F7,
                0xC67178F2};

            /* ========== Preprocessing and padding ========== */
            uint32_t PaddingByteLength = 64 - InputByteLength % 64;
            if (PaddingByteLength < 9) {
                /* if appended 1 and bitlength don't fit, extend padding to another chunk */
                PaddingByteLength += 64;
            }

            uint8_t Padding[PaddingByteLength] alignas(8)= {0};
            Padding[0] = 1;

            /* Writing size in big endian format into the last two 32-bit words of padding */
            uint32_t TotalInputPaddingBitLength = (InputByteLength
                    + PaddingByteLength) * 8;
            uint32_t TotalInputPaddingBitLengthRevertedBytes = ReverseBytes(TotalInputPaddingBitLength);
            uint8_t* TotalInputPaddingBitLengthBytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&TotalInputPaddingBitLengthRevertedBytes);
            for(uint8_t i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8 + i] = TotalInputPaddingBitLengthBytes[i]; //acсessing only by byte
            }

            /* Only need to reverse one word of length of the two, the higher one is always 0 in this implementation for now */

            /* ========== Main loop ========== */
            uint32_t DataIndex = 0;
            for (uint32_t chunk = 0; chunk < (PaddingByteLength + InputByteLength) / 64;
                    chunk++) {

                uint8_t MessageSchedule[64 * 4] alignas(8) = {0};
                uint32_t *MessageScheduleWord = (uint32_t*) MessageSchedule;

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    if (DataIndex < InputByteLength) {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = Data[DataIndex];
                        DataIndex++;
                    } else {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = Padding[DataIndex - InputByteLength];
                        DataIndex++;
                    }
                }

                for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    MessageScheduleWord[i] = ReverseBytes(MessageScheduleWord[i]); //Not reversing doesn't help
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 16; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S0 = RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 15], 7)
                    ^ RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 15], 18)
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] >> 3);
                    uint32_t S1 = RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 2], 17)
                    ^ RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 2], 19)
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] >> 10);
                    MessageScheduleWord[i] = MessageScheduleWord[i - 16]
                    + MessageScheduleWord[i - 7] + S0 + S1;
                }

                uint32_t WorkingVars[8] alignas(8);
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    WorkingVars[i] = Hash[i];
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S1 = RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 6)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 11)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 25);
                    uint32_t ch = (WorkingVars[4] & WorkingVars[5])
                    ^ ((~WorkingVars[4]) & WorkingVars[6]);
                    uint32_t temp1 = WorkingVars[7] + S1 + ch + RoundConstants[i]
                    + *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&MessageSchedule[4 * i]);
                    uint32_t S0 = RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 2)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 13)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 22);
                    uint32_t maj = (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[1])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[2])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[1] & WorkingVars[2]);
                    uint32_t temp2 = S0 + maj;

                    WorkingVars[7] = WorkingVars[6];
                    WorkingVars[6] = WorkingVars[5];
                    WorkingVars[5] = WorkingVars[4];
                    WorkingVars[4] = WorkingVars[3] + temp1;
                    WorkingVars[3] = WorkingVars[2];
                    WorkingVars[2] = WorkingVars[1];
                    WorkingVars[1] = WorkingVars[0];
                    WorkingVars[0] = temp1 + temp2;

                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    Hash[i] += WorkingVars[i];
                }

            }

            for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                Hash[i] = ReverseBytes(Hash[i]);
            }

            //Hash contains wrong value, expected to contain SHA-256

            while (1)
            ;
            return 0;
        }
```

**EDIT**:
Was pointed to a few weak points of my code. Replaced pointer casts with reinterpret casts, forced alignment of all arrays, including byte arrays, via alignas(8); Variable length arrays should not be a problem (default GCC), and documentation doesn't list variable length array as an exception, to which alignas() does not apply. After all of this, the output hasn't changed a single bit. The primary suspect is still the logic. **The code has been updated with these changes.**

**EDIT2**: compiled with `-fno-strict-aliasing` without warnings or errors. No changes to the output.

**EDIT3**: removed unaligned uint32_t memory access during filling padding with bitlength, checked for other unaligned access, most places use byte access, uint32_t arrays are aligned, initial Data[] array has been changed so that the following variables also have to be aligned (length multiple of 4). Final output still doesn't match, but also hasn't changed. **The code has been updated.**

**EDIT4**: I may have gone a little overboard in my attempts to solve it, so I reworked a good part of the code to automate trying stuff out.  This piece of code will be a little longer. I will keep both pieces in this post, because the original is short and has no troubleshooting nonsense, and it's closer to what final implementation should look like. **Code added**.

I added 5 configurable parameters for SHA256 function, which decide, whether (1) padding bit 1 inside padding byte is 0x01 or 0x80 (during preprocessing stage), (2) whether each 4 bytes of data/padding fetched into working array from input or padding array are reversed upon this fetching or not (during processing stage), (3) whether to reverse bytes within words of bitlength in padding (during preprocessing stage), (4) whether 32-bit bitlength of the data+padding goes into last or pre-last 32-bit word of the padding (during preprocessing stage), and (5) whether bytes in output words are reversed (after processing stage).

The test tries all 32 possible combinations of parameters all at once. So far, no match to expected result.

Code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

/* Tools for fighting endianness problems */

typedef enum {
    SHA256_ReverseBytes, SHA256_NotReverseBytes
} SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode;

typedef enum {
    SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_LastWord,
    SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_PreLastWord,
} SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord32Position;

typedef enum {
    SHA256_Padded1As0x01, SHA256_Padded1As0x80
} SHA256_Padded1PositionInByte;

uint32_t LeftRotate(uint32_t data, uint32_t rotation) {
    return (data << rotation) | (data >> (32 - rotation));
}

uint32_t RightRotate(uint32_t data, uint32_t rotation) {
    return (data >> rotation) | (data << (32 - rotation));
}

uint32_t ReverseBytes(uint32_t Input) {
    return ((Input & 0x000000FF) << 24) | ((Input & 0x0000FF00) << 8)
            | ((Input & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((Input & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

void SHA256(uint32_t *Output, uint8_t *InputData, uint32_t InputByteLength,
        SHA256_Padded1PositionInByte Padded1Pos,
        SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode InputDataPaddingReverse,
        SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode PaddingBitLengthWordsReverse,
        SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord32Position PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition,
        SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode OutputReverseBytes) {
    uint32_t Hash[8] = { 0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A,
            0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19 };

    uint32_t RoundConstants[64] = { 0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF,
            0xE9B5DBA5, 0x3956C25B, 0x59F111F1, 0x923F82A4, 0xAB1C5ED5,
            0xD807AA98, 0x12835B01, 0x243185BE, 0x550C7DC3, 0x72BE5D74,
            0x80DEB1FE, 0x9BDC06A7, 0xC19BF174, 0xE49B69C1, 0xEFBE4786,
            0x0FC19DC6, 0x240CA1CC, 0x2DE92C6F, 0x4A7484AA, 0x5CB0A9DC,
            0x76F988DA, 0x983E5152, 0xA831C66D, 0xB00327C8, 0xBF597FC7,
            0xC6E00BF3, 0xD5A79147, 0x06CA6351, 0x14292967, 0x27B70A85,
            0x2E1B2138, 0x4D2C6DFC, 0x53380D13, 0x650A7354, 0x766A0ABB,
            0x81C2C92E, 0x92722C85, 0xA2BFE8A1, 0xA81A664B, 0xC24B8B70,
            0xC76C51A3, 0xD192E819, 0xD6990624, 0xF40E3585, 0x106AA070,
            0x19A4C116, 0x1E376C08, 0x2748774C, 0x34B0BCB5, 0x391C0CB3,
            0x4ED8AA4A, 0x5B9CCA4F, 0x682E6FF3, 0x748F82EE, 0x78A5636F,
            0x84C87814, 0x8CC70208, 0x90BEFFFA, 0xA4506CEB, 0xBEF9A3F7,
            0xC67178F2 };

    /* ========== Preprocessing and padding ========== */
    uint32_t PaddingByteLength = 64 - InputByteLength % 64;
    if (PaddingByteLength < 9) {
        /* if appended 1 and bitlength don't fit, extend padding to another chunk */
        PaddingByteLength += 64;
    }

    uint8_t Padding[PaddingByteLength] alignas(8)= {0};
    if (Padded1Pos == SHA256_Padded1As0x01)
        Padding[0] = 0x01;
    if (Padded1Pos == SHA256_Padded1As0x80)
        Padding[0] = 0x80;

    /* Writing size in big endian format into the last two 32-bit words of padding */
    uint32_t TotalInputPaddingBitLength = (InputByteLength + PaddingByteLength)
            * 8;

    if (PaddingBitLengthWordsReverse == SHA256_ReverseBytes) {
        TotalInputPaddingBitLength = ReverseBytes(TotalInputPaddingBitLength);
    }

    uint8_t *TotalInputPaddingBitLengthBytes =
            reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&TotalInputPaddingBitLength);
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition
                == SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_PreLastWord) {
            Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8 + i] =
                    TotalInputPaddingBitLengthBytes[i]; //Accessing only by byte
        }
        if (PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition
                == SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_LastWord) {
            Padding[PaddingByteLength - 4 + i] =
                    TotalInputPaddingBitLengthBytes[i]; //Accessing only by byte
        }
    }

    /* Only need to reverse one word of length of the two, the higher one is always 0 in this implementation for now */

    /* ========== Main loop ========== */
    uint32_t DataIndex = 0;
    for (uint32_t chunk = 0; chunk < (PaddingByteLength + InputByteLength) / 64;
            chunk++) {

        uint8_t MessageSchedule[64 * 4] alignas(8) = {0};
                uint32_t *MessageScheduleWord = (uint32_t*) MessageSchedule;

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    if (DataIndex < InputByteLength) {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = InputData[DataIndex];
                        DataIndex++;
                    } else {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = Padding[DataIndex - InputByteLength];
                        DataIndex++;
                    }
                }
                if(InputDataPaddingReverse == SHA256_ReverseBytes) {
                    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                        MessageScheduleWord[i] = ReverseBytes(MessageScheduleWord[i]); //Not reversing doesn't help

                    }
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 16; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S0 = RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 15], 7)
                    ^ RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 15], 18)
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] >> 3);
                    uint32_t S1 = RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 2], 17)
                    ^ RightRotate(MessageScheduleWord[i - 2], 19)
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] >> 10);
                    MessageScheduleWord[i] = MessageScheduleWord[i - 16]
                    + MessageScheduleWord[i - 7] + S0 + S1;
                }

                uint32_t WorkingVars[8] alignas(8);
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    WorkingVars[i] = Hash[i];
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S1 = RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 6)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 11)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[4], 25);
                    uint32_t ch = (WorkingVars[4] & WorkingVars[5])
                    ^ ((~WorkingVars[4]) & WorkingVars[6]);
                    uint32_t temp1 = WorkingVars[7] + S1 + ch + RoundConstants[i]
                    + *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&MessageSchedule[4 * i]);
                    uint32_t S0 = RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 2)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 13)
                    ^ RightRotate(WorkingVars[0], 22);
                    uint32_t maj = (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[1])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[2])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[1] & WorkingVars[2]);
                    uint32_t temp2 = S0 + maj;

                    WorkingVars[7] = WorkingVars[6];
                    WorkingVars[6] = WorkingVars[5];
                    WorkingVars[5] = WorkingVars[4];
                    WorkingVars[4] = WorkingVars[3] + temp1;
                    WorkingVars[3] = WorkingVars[2];
                    WorkingVars[2] = WorkingVars[1];
                    WorkingVars[1] = WorkingVars[0];
                    WorkingVars[0] = temp1 + temp2;

                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    Hash[i] += WorkingVars[i];
                }

            }

    if (OutputReverseBytes == SHA256_ReverseBytes) {
        for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Hash[i] = ReverseBytes(Hash[i]);
        }
    }

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Output[i] = Hash[i];
    }
    printf("%#010X\n", Hash[0]);
    fflush(stdout);

}

int main() {
    uint8_t Data[64] alignas(8) = {0};
            Data[0] = 'G';
            uint32_t Data_SHA256[8];

            //unsigned char Data2[] = "Hello, world!";
            //uint32_t Data2_SHA256[8];

            printf("Real SHA256('G',1):\n");
            printf("0x333E0A1E\n\n");
            printf("Real SHA256('Hello, world!',13):\n");
            printf("0x315F5BDB\n\n");

            int testcounter = 0;
            for(uint32_t Padded1Position = SHA256_Padded1As0x01; Padded1Position <= SHA256_Padded1As0x80; Padded1Position++) {
                for(uint32_t ReverseBytesOfInputUponFetching = SHA256_ReverseBytes; ReverseBytesOfInputUponFetching <= SHA256_NotReverseBytes; ReverseBytesOfInputUponFetching++) {
                    for(uint32_t ReverseBytesInsideWordsPaddingBitLength = SHA256_ReverseBytes; ReverseBytesInsideWordsPaddingBitLength <= SHA256_NotReverseBytes; ReverseBytesInsideWordsPaddingBitLength++) {
                        for(uint32_t PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition = SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_LastWord; PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition <= SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord_PreLastWord; PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition++) {
                            for(uint32_t ReverseBytesOutput = SHA256_ReverseBytes; ReverseBytesOutput <= SHA256_NotReverseBytes; ReverseBytesOutput++) {
                                printf("Test: %i\n",testcounter);
                                testcounter++;
                                SHA256(Data_SHA256, Data, 1,
                                        (SHA256_Padded1PositionInByte)Padded1Position,
                                        (SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode)ReverseBytesOfInputUponFetching,
                                        (SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode)ReverseBytesInsideWordsPaddingBitLength,(SHA256_64BitBitLengthLowerWord32Position)PaddingBitLengthLowerWordPosition,(SHA256_ReverseByteConfigurationMode)ReverseBytesOutput);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            while(1);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `*(uint32_t*) (&Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8 + 4 * i])` and all similar expressions: That's an aliasing violation and your code therefore has undefined behavior. You are not allowed to simply cast one pointer type to another and use the object through it. There are only few exceptions where this is allowed.

Comment: Also `PaddingByteLength` is not a compile-time constant and therefore it can't be used as an array length in standard C++. If this compiled for you, then the compiler is using the variable-length array (VLA) extension for the `Padding` array, which is a C feature, but not a C++ one.

Comment: @user17732522, interesting I have been using such aliasing for very long without a problem (initially, much greater part of the code here worked with such aliasing). Will have to change it in a few places then (will have to think how). Regarding VLA, I think it works, but it could be activated in eclipse's gcc, I didn't get any errors or warnings. Do you suspect one of these could be the issue? Because the aliasing thing definitely works ok, so I will change it to respect the spec, but it's not why the whole thing doesn't work in this instance. I also tried bitlength in another word. Still nah

Comment: I have not verified the logic of your code, but yes, the aliasing issue can very well cause the program to not behave the way you want it to, at least with optimizations enabled. Also, you do not assure anywhere that the array is correctly aligned for `uint32_t`, so even with e.g. the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag, which disables the problematic optimizations, you may still access memory unaligned, which is also UB according to the standard, and in practice the effect depends at least on the CPU architecture.

Comment: Also note that the aliasing rule has always existed since the first standardization of C and in all C and C++ standards since and compilers have also always been using it for optimization purposes.

Comment: GCC supports VLAs with the default settings. You can give the `-pedantic-errors` flag if you want GCC to behave standard-conforming and fail to compile the VLA and other constructs that are not compatible with the standard. If you use just `-pedantic` instead, it will still compile, but at least warn you about it.

Comment: @user17732522 so for the time being, I can assume the VLA part is ok. I also stepped through things with debugger with the aliasing part, with test data. It worked. Regarding memory alignment, I didn't check it. I'm off to fix aliasing issues and check memory alignment then.

Comment: If you stepped through the whole program with the debugger, then you should see which step produces the wrong result, right? Or how do you expect that to verify the aliasing issue is not the cause? You can't check that with code in isolation. The optimizer's decisions can depend on a lot of context.

Comment: @user17732522 it gets very messy very quickly, and I can't directly compare it with any other implementation, because they're structured differently, I don't have anything to compare it to, not in any ready state. It's theoretically possible, but I will spend several hours just settings things up so I can compare them, probably (I'm not that great at it)

Comment: [OT]: `while (1);` is pedantically UB.

Comment: Fixed pointer casts with reinterpret cast. Fixed memory alignment with alignas for all arrays (including byte array). Numerical result is identical to the bit. While(1) is there for program to never stop, habit from embedded. I doubt it can cause this? Pretty sure I messed up logic more than anything else.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not only pedantically. If OP was using Clang with optimizations enabled that wouldn't go well. GCC is a bit nicer about it.

Comment: @Ilya If you fixed things mentioned in the comments that turned out to not be relevant to your question and given that there aren't any actual answers yet, you can update the code in your question accordingly. Then we won't be focused on irrelevant issues anymore. That being said, I don't know whether GCC will honor `alignas` on a VLA. That's something you should probably verify in documentation.

Comment: "_Fixed pointer casts with reinterpret cast._": That doesn't change anything by the way. `reinterpret_cast` is equivalent to the C-style cast and is still the same aliasing violation when dereferenced. If you want to verify that the aliasing violations aren't the cause, compile with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag.

Comment: Your `Padding` array has size `PaddingByteLength` which has value `63`, so `Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8]` is not going to be properly aligned for `uint32_t` even if `Padding` itself is. Also `Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8 + 4 * i]` is out-of-bounds when accessed as `uint32_t` and `i` is `1`.

Comment: I agree about misalignment, but out of bounds doesn't happen. Padding[PaddingByteLength - 8 + 4 * i]) for PaddingByteLength of 10 means we read Padding 6 || 7 || 8 || 9, no out of bounds. But yes, I see how it can be not aligned. I will fix that and update the code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, disregard that last part. No idea why I thought it was out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works! First of all, bit length that is appended at the end of the last padded 512-bit chunk of data, is the bit length of input data, **excluding** padding. Second of all, my frankenstein monster parameter tester found the correct combination of parameters (where to revert bytes and where not, etc.).

Additionally, I have manually inlined helper functions (rotate integer, reverse bytes), and my implementation is one function that does it all. Accepts only 32-bit integer as input byte length. Only byte memory access to data, input data doesn't need to be aligned. Requires `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

```
#include <cstdint>

void SHA256(uint8_t *Output, uint8_t *InputData, uint32_t InputByteLength) {
    uint32_t Hash[8] = { 0x6A09E667, 0xBB67AE85, 0x3C6EF372, 0xA54FF53A,
            0x510E527F, 0x9B05688C, 0x1F83D9AB, 0x5BE0CD19 };

    uint32_t RoundConstants[64] = { 0x428A2F98, 0x71374491, 0xB5C0FBCF,
            0xE9B5DBA5, 0x3956C25B, 0x59F111F1, 0x923F82A4, 0xAB1C5ED5,
            0xD807AA98, 0x12835B01, 0x243185BE, 0x550C7DC3, 0x72BE5D74,
            0x80DEB1FE, 0x9BDC06A7, 0xC19BF174, 0xE49B69C1, 0xEFBE4786,
            0x0FC19DC6, 0x240CA1CC, 0x2DE92C6F, 0x4A7484AA, 0x5CB0A9DC,
            0x76F988DA, 0x983E5152, 0xA831C66D, 0xB00327C8, 0xBF597FC7,
            0xC6E00BF3, 0xD5A79147, 0x06CA6351, 0x14292967, 0x27B70A85,
            0x2E1B2138, 0x4D2C6DFC, 0x53380D13, 0x650A7354, 0x766A0ABB,
            0x81C2C92E, 0x92722C85, 0xA2BFE8A1, 0xA81A664B, 0xC24B8B70,
            0xC76C51A3, 0xD192E819, 0xD6990624, 0xF40E3585, 0x106AA070,
            0x19A4C116, 0x1E376C08, 0x2748774C, 0x34B0BCB5, 0x391C0CB3,
            0x4ED8AA4A, 0x5B9CCA4F, 0x682E6FF3, 0x748F82EE, 0x78A5636F,
            0x84C87814, 0x8CC70208, 0x90BEFFFA, 0xA4506CEB, 0xBEF9A3F7,
            0xC67178F2 };

    /* ========== Preprocessing and padding ========== */
    uint32_t PaddingByteLength = 64 - InputByteLength % 64;
    if (PaddingByteLength < 9) {
        /* if appended 1 and bitlength don't fit into current chunk, extend padding to another chunk */
        PaddingByteLength += 64;

    }

    uint8_t Padding[PaddingByteLength] = { 0 };
    Padding[0] = 0x80; //Append "1"

    /* Writing size in big endian format into the last two 32-bit words of padding */
    uint32_t InputBitLength = (InputByteLength) * 8;
    uint8_t *InputBitLengthBytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&InputBitLength);
    /* Reverse bytes */
    InputBitLengthBytes[0] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[3];
    InputBitLengthBytes[3] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[0];
    InputBitLengthBytes[0] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[3];
    InputBitLengthBytes[1] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[2];
    InputBitLengthBytes[2] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[1];
    InputBitLengthBytes[1] ^= InputBitLengthBytes[2];
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Padding[PaddingByteLength - 4 + i] = InputBitLengthBytes[i]; //Accessing only by byte
    }

    /* ========== Main loop ========== */
    uint32_t DataIndex = 0;
    for (uint32_t chunk = 0; chunk < (PaddingByteLength + InputByteLength) / 64;
            chunk++) {

        uint8_t MessageSchedule[64 * 4] alignas(4);
                uint32_t *MessageScheduleWord = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*> (MessageSchedule);

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    if (DataIndex < InputByteLength) {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = InputData[DataIndex];
                        DataIndex++;
                    } else {
                        MessageSchedule[i] = Padding[DataIndex - InputByteLength];
                        DataIndex++;
                    }
                }

                /* Reverse data bytes upon fetching */
                for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+0] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+3];
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+3] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+0];
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+0] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+3];
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+1] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+2];
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+2] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+1];
                    MessageSchedule[4*i+1] ^= MessageSchedule[4*i+2];
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 16; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S0 = ((MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] >> 7) | (MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] << (32 - 7)))
                    ^ ((MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] >> 18) | (MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] << (32 - 18)))
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 15] >> 3);
                    uint32_t S1 = ((MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] >> 17) | (MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] << (32 - 17)))
                    ^ ((MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] >> 19) | (MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] << (32 - 19)))
                    ^ (MessageScheduleWord[i - 2] >> 10);
                    MessageScheduleWord[i] = MessageScheduleWord[i - 16]
                    + MessageScheduleWord[i - 7] + S0 + S1;
                }

                uint32_t WorkingVars[8];
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    WorkingVars[i] = Hash[i];
                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
                    uint32_t S1 = ((WorkingVars[4] >> 6) | (WorkingVars[4] << (32 - 6)))
                    ^ ((WorkingVars[4] >> 11) | (WorkingVars[4] << (32 - 11)))
                    ^ ((WorkingVars[4] >> 25) | (WorkingVars[4] << (32 - 25)));
                    uint32_t ch = (WorkingVars[4] & WorkingVars[5])
                    ^ ((~WorkingVars[4]) & WorkingVars[6]);
                    uint32_t temp1 = WorkingVars[7] + S1 + ch + RoundConstants[i]
                    + MessageScheduleWord[i];
                    uint32_t S0 = ((WorkingVars[0] >> 2) | (WorkingVars[0] << (32 - 2)))
                    ^ ((WorkingVars[0] >> 13) | (WorkingVars[0] << (32 - 13)))
                    ^ ((WorkingVars[0] >> 22) | (WorkingVars[0] << (32 - 22)));
                    uint32_t maj = (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[1])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[0] & WorkingVars[2])
                    ^ (WorkingVars[1] & WorkingVars[2]);
                    uint32_t temp2 = S0 + maj;

                    WorkingVars[7] = WorkingVars[6];
                    WorkingVars[6] = WorkingVars[5];
                    WorkingVars[5] = WorkingVars[4];
                    WorkingVars[4] = WorkingVars[3] + temp1;
                    WorkingVars[3] = WorkingVars[2];
                    WorkingVars[2] = WorkingVars[1];
                    WorkingVars[1] = WorkingVars[0];
                    WorkingVars[0] = temp1 + temp2;

                }

                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    Hash[i] += WorkingVars[i];
                }

            }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        Output[4 * i + 0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(Hash[4 * i]);
        Output[4 * i + 1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(Hash[4 * i] >> 8);
        Output[4 * i + 2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(Hash[4 * i] >> 16);
        Output[4 * i + 3] = static_cast<uint8_t>(Hash[4 * i] >> 24);
    }

}
```